# no element found - SQL statement looks good though

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone see what is wrong with this line of code?  using **php/mysql**

```
$sqlInsert="INSERT INTO sched_trades_proposed (id,originalDate,originalUserid,originalRot,original_sched_main_id,proposedDate,proposedUserid,proposedRot,proposed_sched_main_id,timeStampedProposal,randomHash) VALUES('','".$originalDate."',".$_SESSION[userid].",$originalRotation,$original_sched_main_id,'".$proposedDate."',$proposedRad,$proposedRotation,$proposed_sched_main_id,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'".$randomHash."')";
```

fire bug says "no element found" in `jquery-1.8.2.js (line 7209, col 314)` and points to this **`INSERT`** statement.  I don’t see anything wrong with the insert statement.  I realize fire bug isn't **`server`** side.  I am still trying to solve the error though.  If I comment out this line of code I get no error.

the surrounding code is:

```
$randomHash=sha1(rand(1,1000));
$sqlInsert="INSERT INTO sched_trades_proposed (id,originalDate,originalUserid,originalRot,original_sched_main_id,proposedDate,proposedUserid,proposedRot,proposed_sched_main_id,timeStampedProposal,randomHash) VALUES('','".$originalDate."',".$_SESSION[userid].",$originalRotation,$original_sched_main_id,'".$proposedDate."',$proposedRad,$proposedRotation,$proposed_sched_main_id,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'".$randomHash."')";
echo '<p>'.$sqlInsert;
$resultInsert=mysql_query($sqlInsert);
```

when I manually insert the **`INSERT`** statement into **mySQL** it gives no errors...But I am getting while trying through the web page?

Here is an example with data in the outputted INSERT statement which all looks good:

```
INSERT INTO sched_trades_proposed (id,originalDate,originalUserid,originalRot,original_sched_main_id,proposedDate,proposedUserid,proposedRot,proposed_sched_main_id,timeStampedProposal,randomHash) VALUES('','2013-01-10',10,7,710,'2013-01-14',3,19,723,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'f33f7ae89c2c6ab8e29a3cb0a97bb1f9456aacba')
```

FYI: the original id is auto incremented, so I insert a '' as the first column which is kosher.

Comment: You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples to get you started.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank you Andy and Joseph.  Learning and reading now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug says so because you echoed it to the client, and the client HTML parsing is confused because of that. Perhaps because that echo got into a wrong place? Remove that echo. Why do you need it? Or place that echo at a place which would not interfere with your HTML code. e.g. perhaps wrap a div/span around where that echo is?

Comment: Amit, that is gold.  That explains why Firebug is showing the error.  I use the echo as an error check only.

Comment: I deleted the echo $sql and the error is gone. Thank you for explaining it to me as well.  I wasn't even in the ballpark.. but it is such an obvious explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The INSERT returns no data or acknowledgement by itself. If you are using jQuery to display the inserted data, you will need to run another SELECT to get it again. You can also just return the primary key of the inserted row(assuming MySql for the link although the same thing works [with PDO). See this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)